# Strange ```tableofcontents```error in XeTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, debugging, e-tex, morewrites

I am currently typesetting a book with XeTeX and there's a strange error in overleaf:

```
\alloc@ ...else \errmessage {No room for a new #2}
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.41 {\sloppy\tableofcontents
                             }
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tf@toc 
l.41 {\sloppy\tableofcontents
                             }
A number should have been here; I inserted '0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

I am also getting just `output.toc` printed as a toc item. There also seems to be some issue with some of the book template's packages:

```
\usepackage{morewrites} %more helper files to write to
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{18}
```

Working with TeX Live on Macintosh gives the following error message:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
<recently read> \reserveinserts 
                                
l.283 \reserveinserts
                     {18}
--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.
```

Would someone have an idea how to solve this weird bug? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try removing `\usepackage{etex}` and `\reserveinserts{18}`, they're really outdated commands.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, this messes everything up for the template and delivers a broken document.

Comment: Sorry, but the details you give are not sufficient to say more. Can you present a minimal example of a document that fails?

Comment: If the template requires the etex package it is likely to have been broken since about 2015, probably easy to fix it not to use that but without any example shown it will be very hard to help